# Adding markers on a seaborn lineplot for every few observations

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a dataframe that I want to plot a seaborn lineplot with markers. If I set "marker=True", the markers will be added on every points.

Is there a way to add markers using sns.lineplot for every few observations (e.g., every 20 observations)?

The following figure is an example:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Filter your dataframe for points [0, 12, 16, ....] or whatever you like and add a scatterplot with markers to your lineplot? See for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45964066/8881141)

Comment: Good idea! I will try it!